# Remote job asking me for holder name bank name email address and phone number associated with bank account

Tags: bank-account, scams

This is the email that was sent to me i'm wondering if this is a scam 
can funds in your account be accessed with your holder name bank name email address associated with your account and phone number

> During the work you use bitcoins for working with customers.
>   It is necessary for customers. Use the services of our partners at a lower price, you can only for business purposes.
>   Services and goods which you will buy for customers through bitcoins for low price:
>
> - Web Design;
> - MySQL Database;
> - Set up VoIP number;
> - Database Servers;
> - Stock exchange services;
> - Hosting;
> - Virtual private servers.
>
> To  start  working  with  Bitcoin, you need to fill up your wallet. We
>   will provide you money via Zelle system.
>
> To do this, we need to know:
>
> Your Holder name:
>   Your Bank name:
>   Your Email address associated with account:
>   Your phone number:
>
> There is no fee to receive bitcoins, and many wallets let you control how large a fee to pay when spending.
>   Most wallets have reasonable default fees, and higher fees can encourage faster confirmation of your transactions.
>   After receiving electronic transfer, you will have to fill up your Bitcoin wallet.
>
> We will send you 2-3 transactions through Zelle.
>   Have you ever used electronic transfer (Zelle)?
>   Do you have online banking active?
>   Do you have business bank account?

Comment: "Services and goods **which you will buy for customers** through bitcoins for low price".  That raises a giant flag for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What risks are there acting as a broker between PayPal and electronic bank transfers?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/63056/what-risks-are-there-acting-as-a-broker-between-paypal-and-electronic-bank-trans)

Comment: You said this is a "job" where you are presumably an "employee."  When was the last time you heard of a job asking its employees to use their own bank accounts for business purposes?!

Answer (score 11):

This is almost certainly an old scam in a new bottle. I'll lay you odds that they would "deposit" money in your account, you'd use that money to buy bitcoins and send them to the "vendors", and after a few days the bank would figure out that the deposit was bogus (bad check, money stolen from somebody else's account), and debit your account for the amount of the deposit. You'd be left on the hook for the cost of the bitcoins, there's no calling those back or getting a refund.

There are a bunch of scams that take advantage of consumers that don't realize that some bank transactions can be reversed and some can't.

Comment: Even if the originating transaction never gets reversed, this is almost certainly a scam. The OP is being used as a money mule to convert cash into bitcoin without a clear connection back to the scammer (the account the Zelle transaction originates from is probably stolen). Sometimes, scammers don't want to actually steal anything from a victim, they just want to use the victim as a pawn in a bigger scam. Even if your own finances aren't compromised, you may still be getting scammed.

Answer (score 2):

If there is money to change hands, one need only to use Zelle, which requires an email address associated with one's bank account. The bank information need not be sent to the money-sender. A mobile phone number can also be used. Only one of the two items is required. The rest of the information demands point to a scam. Beware.